# nginx redirects do not show when browsing in Private Mode

Tags: nginx, 301-redirect

I have `domain1.com` that needs to redirect to `domain2.com`. My `nginx` config under `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` is this,

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    server_name www.domain1.com domain1.com;
    return 301 https://www.domain2.com$request_uri;
}
```

This works when browsing normally. However, when browsing in private mode the original site still loads without any redirects. Also when I tried changing the domain in Google Search Console it tried testing the redirects with a random set of URLs and failed, but the links do redirect when browsing normally.

Why is this happening and how do I ensure the redirect happens regardless of what mode you are browsing in?

Comment: Test your site using `curl`. Browsers are not a good test method. If you can see the original site, where is it being hosted? Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view your entire configuration across all included files.

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks. This is what I see with `curl -I --http2 https://www.domain1.com` ```HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Wed, 19 May 2021 06:35:28 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 178
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://www.domain2.com/```

Comment: I had to clear the cache in Cloudflare since the site DNS is managed through that and remove the CF proxies. It works now.